Confidence regions for (mu,sigma) normal distribution
At the normal distribution, I want to find a confidence region for the bidimensional parameter $(\mu,\sigma)$. Is there a better way of doing so than calculating the Cartesian product of the two separate confidence intervals corrected by Bonferroni?

It depends on how you are estimating them.  There are many different ways to do so!

There's also choice in how you want to form your region (there's multiple ways to define a region with coverage $1-\alpha$ of which there's a few common approaches). Indeed even with a univariate interval there's more than one commonly used option (e.g. equal tail vs shortest interval).

In a dream scenario, I would like to have an ellipsoidal confidence region with coverage probability of exactly $1-\alpha$. If this has been done, do you know any proper referemce covering this topic (preferrably a book)?

The conditional distribution of typical estimators of $\sigma$ won't be symmetric (note that $\sigma$ is non-negative as are plausible estimators of it) -- are you sure you want ellipsoidal regions? I guess you could transform your scale to estimate some transformed $\sigma$ and have your favourite estimator of that be symmetrically distributed or nearly so.


Bookwise, to understand the range of choices that whuber and I have mentioned (so that you can narrow down the question a bit), you might start with a standard statistical reference on inference. Perhaps Casella and Berger?   If you want something simpler there are many options to begin on, though they may not quite get you all the way to what you need. 2. In the hopes of  more quickly narrowing the question a bit,  do you just want to work with the estimators $\bar{x}$ and $s_{n-1}$ (the usual Bessel-corrected standard deviation perhaps?


Going back to references for a moment, a useful topic to be familiar with when playing with CIs is that of pivotal quantities. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity ...

One way to approach constructing a confidence region would be to construct a joint test and find (for a given sample) the set of values for the parameters that would not lead to rejection. It doesn't solve the choice problem on how to pick the boundary but may convert those choices to a more familiar setting.

If you can get hold of it, there's a nice paper that covers a fair bit of literature on JCRs for $(\mu,\sigma)$ under normality, discusses a number of regions (exact and approximate) and discusses issues of robustness: Arnold, B.C. and Shavelle, R.M. (1998),
"Joint Confidence Sets for the Mean and Variance of a Normal Distribution,"
The American Statistician
Vol. 52, No. 2 (May), pp. 133-140.  This might help you focus your question perhaps. $:$ ― and on a different note there's an R package jocre that has a function csetMV that covers some approaches for JCRs for $\mu$ and $\sigma$

I've just noticed that the Arnold & Shavelle reference is in the ref list for that function (albeit with Shavelle misspelled). If I'd looked there for references  first, that might have saved me some time. Its ref list includes a more recent paper on minimum area regions

For the usual (unbiased moment-based) estimators much work has been done.  For instance, CIs for arbitrary linear combinations of $m=\hat\mu$ and $s^2=\hat{\sigma^2}$ have been analytically worked out (they provide CIs for the arithmetic means of Lognormal distributions, for instance).  I believe that might have appeared in Odeh & Owen (1980).  For Maximum Likelihood estimates you can apply the usual machinery--but I would recommend re-expressing the parameters in terms of $\mu$ and either $\log\sigma$ or $1/\sigma^2$ (the precision), expecting near-circular regions for them.
